Best method for sequential small size Hermitian smallest eigenpair problem
I am working on a perhaps rather strange problem. To find the smallest eigenvalue and its eigenvector, for a large number (a few billions) of small (20 * 20 to 200 * 200) Hermitian matrices. These matrices may have rather similar eigenvectors, with its smallest eigenvalue always slightly larger than one. And the eigenvector have all elements with modulus close to 1, where the phase part carries the desired information.
Seriously, the problem is simple: no multiplicity of eigenvalue, no memory limit and thus no restart, the matrices are very "generic", no isolated subspaces (not sure whether I get the point).
I want to use precondition and early stop to accelerate this program. As a engineering student, I tried my best to read a bunch of articles, with an emphesis on the "PRIMME" software.
As far as I know, common methods are about finding a subspace where the projection of the real eigenvector onit is of maximized length. Moreover, with a smart orthonomalization scheme, we can establish a concise basis of this subspace, the tridiagonal one, on which the eigen values are easy to find.
The methods mainly differ on how to determine the next direction to extend the subspace, where multiple optimization methods are introduced.
STATHOPOULOS gives two optimized methods, the JDQMR and GD+1 (I am not really sure what these terms refers to). But this article tackles the limited memory case.
My question is, in my rather simplified case, which algorithm will work the best, for me to dig into. My math knowledge is very primitive, and the heavy worklod lies in program optimization, I cannot figure out which is best.
Another point is to roughly estimate the ratio of $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1$ ($\lambda_1$ is the smallest), to estimate the error in eigenvector, so that I can stop iteration early.

I wonder if you could bin the matrices into nearby "bunches" via kd tree or something similar, then solve exactly for one matrix per bunch, and using this exact solution as a a starting point for an iterative algorithm for the other matrices in the bunch. This way you can reduce the amount of work.

@user619894 That is basically what I want to do, and I am wondering which iterative method suits for the my condition and can best use the startpoint, a small matrix with a mostly convincing start points, but may be seriously deviated from time to time.
